# Zabbix - monthly availability graph, or for selected filter period

Tags: zabbix

is it possible to create bar graph like it is displayed when you create availability report and use Show command? It creates availability graph for current year only.
I need to create the same graph for current month, or better for current filter date period which availability is shown.

Thanks for suggestions.